# Trouble finding the right CSS to modify

Tags: css, drupal

I am building a site using Drupal 7 and have run into a CSS issue. I am trying to wrap everything on this registration page in the center and at the same time reduce the width of the drop down buttons. I believe I've narrowed the problem to my logintobaggan (drupal module) css sheet. But the button "widths" seem to be from the foundation.min.css (according to chrome elements). How would you guys approach this CSS problem? I am relatively new, so please don't be too harsh ;). Thanks!

http://medicaldoctorapps.com/user/register

Answer (score 1):

I would get Firebug or similar in-browser development tool, select the element you are interested in seeing the CSS properties for, and then see exactly which rules are being applied or overridden.  You can even modify the CSS right there in the tool until you get want you want.

From such a tool, I can see that the button widths are not explicitly defined, but are basically derived from the amount of padding (5px) around the text string inside the button.

The rules are defined starting on line 41 of this file:

http://medicaldoctorapps.com/sites/all/modules/logintoboggan/logintoboggan.css?mgqhxk

Comment: Thanks, this is a great start.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried adding max-width and/or center tags to the .toboggan-unified.login #register-form and .toboggan-unified.register #login-form part of the logintoboggan .css file... not working. What about conditions in the container on line 2 that might get it to do what I want it to? e.g. div.toboggan-container

Comment: @user1985096 I don't know how to help, as I don;'t know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: trying to center and wrap everything nicely on our registration page: http://medicaldoctorapps.com/user/register

Comment: Sorry I thought you were talking about the two main button near the top.

Comment: They are showing as centered to me (with exception of select boxes). I just noticed you were mentioned width of select boxes. That CSS is at line 1 of http://medicaldoctorapps.com/sites/all/themes/touchm/stylesheets/foundation.min.css?mgqhxk It looks like it is default style from the CSS reset that is being used.